# Error building mvfs

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

I am trying to build `mvfs` so that I can run IBM Rational ClearCase on a CentOS 6.4 machine. I have all the dependencies installed so I cd to the `mvfs_src` folder and get the following error while running `make`:

```
/var/adm/rational/clearcase/mvfs/mvfs_src/mvfs_linux_mvops.c: In function ‘mvop_linux_open_kernel’:
/var/adm/rational/clearcase/mvfs/mvfs_src/mvfs_linux_mvops.c:1454: error: implicit declaration of function ‘get_empty_filp’
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
/var/adm/rational/clearcase/mvfs/mvfs_src/mvfs_linux_mvops.c:1454: error: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
make[2]: *** [/var/adm/rational/clearcase/mvfs/mvfs_src/mvfs_linux_mvops.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/var/adm/rational/clearcase/mvfs/mvfs_src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As of [commit e81e3f4dca6c54116a24aec217d2c15c6f58ada5](https://git.kernel.org/linus/e81e3f4dca6c54116a24aec217d2c15c6f58ada5) (which went into Linux v2.6.33), the function `get_empty_filp()` becomes internal and is no longer exported to modules:

```
commit e81e3f4dca6c54116a24aec217d2c15c6f58ada5
Author: Eric Paris 
Date:   Fri Dec 4 15:47:36 2009 -0500

    fs: move get_empty_filp() deffinition to internal.h

    All users outside of fs/ of get_empty_filp() have been removed.  This patch
    moves the definition from the include/ directory to internal.h so no new
    users crop up and removes the EXPORT_SYMBOL.  […]
```

The same commit appears to have been backported to the CentOS kernel 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6, since it has the same function declared in `fs/internal.h`:

```
linux-2.6.32-358.14.1.el6/fs/internal.h:88:extern struct file *get_empty_filp(void);
```

In other words, not only `mvfs` is out of date, it is even out of date *for CentOS.* My guess is that the only way to fix this is to get a newer `mvfs` version (if one exists), or…downgrade the kernel.

Comment: i don't think i can get a newer version of mvfs. what kernel should i downgrade to ?